Change BaseUrl of injected HttpClient
I'm currently working on a .NET MAUI app and I'm using DI for working with HttpClient and communicating with my backend.
In the settings, the user can change the URL of the backend, but obviously, the app still requests the old URL, as the Service classes were already injected.
In my MauiProgram.cs I do the following to register the client:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("APIClient", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Preferences.Get(Constants.SETTING_SERVER, "http://192.168.10.125:5000/")));

builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("APIClient"));

Here is a sample Service class:
public class SampleAPIService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public SampleAPIService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    

     // API specific things like GET, POST and so on
     
}

Basically, the change in the Settings does change the return value of Preferences.Get(Constants.SETTING_SERVER). Is there a best practice for my problem? Do I need to inject the Factory rather than the client directly?

If you are using named clients, then you definitely need to inject the factory. The second line in your DI is a BAD practice. Think if someone will create another named client APIClien2 and will do the same. He will override your APIClien in the DI. So either you use an unnamed client and just inject the HttpClient in the constructor or you inject the factory and create the named client on demand.

@Artur When injecting the factory: Wouldn't the problem be the same? How would the service know that it has to create a new HttpClient because there's a new BaseAddress? Same question for the unnamed client

It should create a new client every time it needs it. So if the client config is changed, it will get a new config

@Artur So basically all I have to do is inject the factory instead of the client and it will care about creating new instances when my URL in the Preferences changes?

@Artur When talking about injecting the factory, is it just builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); in my MauiProgram.cs?

"Yes" for both questions. You just need to make sure, the place where you inject and create the client is not singleton, so you won't finish with the same client for the entire app lifetime.

@Artur To sum it up: The only line of code referring to injecting HttpClient in my MauiProgram.cs looks like this: builder.Services.AddHttpClient("APIClient", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Preferences.Get(Constants.SETTING_SERVER, "http://192.168.10.125:5000/")));
And in the services I get the injected HttpClientFactory and call facotory.CreateClient("APIClient") in the constructor?

Correct (a few more chars to satisfy SO comments min length)

@Artur Would you mind posting the solution as an answer so I can accept it?

@Artur I implemented it the way you suggested, but it seems that the framework does not create a new client when the value in the Preferences is changed. Do I have to tell the factory that there were made some changes?

As @Artur advised, I made following changes to my code:
MauiProgram.cs - injecting the Factory rather than a client:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("APIClient", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Preferences.Get(Constants.SETTING_SERVER, "http://192.168.10.125:5000/")));

I changed to my Services to look like this (Factory is injected and HttpClient is created on every request):
public class SampleAPIService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private HttpClient GetHttpClient() => _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("APIClient"); 

    public SampleAPIService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task PostAsJson<T>(string url, T request)
        {
            using var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, request);
            if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                throw new Exception(await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }

            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }   

     // more API specific things like GET, POST and so on
     
}

